# Angular 7 image backgroud for View composed of 2 or more components?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

this is my html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to set an image as background for the home view that is divided in 2 components (navbarComponent and homeComponent -selector ) but this will not be aplied in the others component (e.g contactComponent -supose to use other image, with the selectors app-navbar, and app-contact).

So how can I use an image as backgroud for the view composed by the app-navbar and app-home ???

Answer (score 0):

Why not to add the background image as a CSS class for your `<body>` tag that you can define in the global `styles.css` file and then under the page/route y'd like this to show up, add that class name to the `<body>` tag using one of these two options.

The first option is the easiest but less recommended:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.document.body.classList.add('test');
}
```

The second option (my personal recommendation) is to implement the custom rendering class from the `@angular/core` package:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

export class myCoolComponent implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'test');
   }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'test');
  }
```

Hope this will help you!